# Excel - Create custom scale for y-axis beyond the "Format Axis" options

Tags: excel-charts

In Excel (Microsoft 365 apps for business), I see that for my line chart I can set the axis options under Format Axis > Axis Options, such as bounds and units (reference: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-scale-of-the-vertical-value-axis-in-a-chart-05973661-e56a-4486-a9f3-f9ce41df0021).

Instead, I would like to have a custom scale for this axis using the values pasted below. No, logarithmic is not a suitable option (10, 100, 1000) as the client doesn't accept that. How do I create such a custom scale for the y-axis intervals?

0
16
40
70
200
300
500
1000
2000
30000

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft support stated this is not possible in Excel --
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-create-custom-scale-for-y-axis-beyond-the/bc59d7e0-22df-49f1-853f-486ed83c68f2